# Java Swing - Using JScrollPane and Having it scroll back to top

Tags: java, swing

I'm using JScrollPane to allow scrolling in a JFrame that has a text component that's serving as a text editor.  What I want to do, after setting the text in this editor, is have  it scroll back up to the top, so you can see what's at the beginning of the file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 148):

Calling [setCaretPosition(0)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)) on your text component will cause it to scroll to the top.

Comment: You are right, the problem was that the caret was at the end of the text component. It also works after calling 'setText(...)' on the text editor. (tested with a JEditorPane instance as text panel inside the JScrollPane).

Answer (score 42):

Just in case you are not using a text component take a look at the thread posted here.... [Setting Scroll Bar on a JScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166072/setting-scroll-bar-on-a-jscrollpane)

Their solution is to spin off a thread via invokeLater

```
final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() { 
       scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
   }
});
```

Comment: This is the closest answer to my question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961012/how-to-set-scroll-to-the-top-jpanel-that-has-multiple-jtextareas-inside-jscrol?noredirect=1#comment73017112_42961012 However, how can use this method if there is panel inside JScrollPane?

Comment: `invokeLater` doesn't spin off a thread, it just enqueues an event to be executed after the current event (e.g. button click, or whatever is the context of the code which calls `invokeLater`) and any other already-enqueued events finish.

Answer (score 10):

This will make the work:

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method `setCaretPosition(0)` just after `setText(String t)` of your text component.

Comment: Copy of @Craig's earlier answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use [JComponent.scrollRectToVisible()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible(java.awt.Rectangle))

If you need more info, [here's an article](http://www.chka.de/swing/components/scrolling.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
 scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0,0));
```

According to the JavaDocs setViewPosition() behaves like this:

> Sets the view coordinates that appear in the upper left hand corner of the viewport, does nothing if there's no view.

Comment: This didn't work for me - the ScrollPane jumps to the top then immediately drops down to the bottom again.

Comment: It worked for me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  I have a JTable inside my JScrollPane.

Comment: @jwoolard Yes, the solution presented here doesn't work in a number of cases I've encountered. BUT, take note of the solution I posed this morning.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how:

```
textArea.setSelectionStart(0);
textArea.setSelectionEnd(0);
```