# How to let scrollbar's default position be at top?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel in a JScrollPane, and the JPanel contains many small JPanels. But the default position of scrollbar is not at the top, thus the small JPanels isn't shown from the first one. How to let scrollbar's default position be at top?

My code is simplified and looks like this:

```
JFrame resultFrame = new JFrame("Searching Result");

JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
listPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    listPanel.add(smallPanel) // smallPanel is created in another class, which is related to i.
}
JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(listPanel);
scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 750));

resultFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
resultFrame.setContentPane(scrollPanel);
resultFrame.pack();
resultFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
resultFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `scrollPanel.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);` [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544758/how-to-adjust-position-of-scroll-in-the-scrollpane) is a related thread.

Comment: After playing around with your example, the `JScrollPane` offset starts at `0x0` for me just fine

Comment: @StefanLindner, Yes, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166072/setting-scroll-bar-on-a-jscrollpane ?

Comment: @Subala Thank you! I check this again. `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` works, meanwhile, just `scrollPanel.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0)` doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: @GAOFangshu This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551542/swingutilities-invokelater-why-is-it-needed)