# Scroll text area to top after it has been filled

Tags: java, loops, textarea, awt

I have a few text areas that are filled with loops of information. Is it possible to make it 'jump' or scroll back to the top automatically after the loop has completed, so that the user sees it from the start and not the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291115/java-swing-using-jscrollpane-and-having-it-scroll-back-to-top

Comment: Are you referring to an AWT based `TextArea` or a Swing based `JTextArea`?  Please be specific.

Comment: Why are you using AWT components in this millennium?  The few people that did use them have largely forgotten how!

Comment: I'm only using the AWT TextArea as I don't like the way Swing displays without a border, all my other components are Swing!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating a new TextArea which acts as a sort of buffer (and isn't displayed). The loop writes to this area and when completed gets the text from that and sets it to the required TextArea.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `setCaretPosition()` to set the cursor at position 0 of the TextArea. That usually works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use setUpdatePolicy with NEVER_UPDATE, and make sure the setUpdatePolicy comes before setting any text to the JTextArea. In my example I initialize a JTextArea without any text and call setUpdatePolicy right after.

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
((DefaultCaret)jTextArea.getCaret()).setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```