# How do i set the scrollbar in JScrollPane to the top? Using borderlayout. the bar always scroll to the bottom of my content.

Tags: eclipse, jscrollpane, jtextarea

//created a JScrollPane and when i run it the scrollbars will automatically go to the most bottom of my textarea, but i need it to be on top.
thank you in advance! =)

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(22, 86, 262, 57);
content.add(scrollPane);
```

//the text area used

```
JTextArea txtrTryingTryingTrying = new JTextArea();
scrollPane.setViewportView(txtrTryingTryingTrying);
txtrTryingTryingTrying.setText("-------");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing - Using JScrollPane and Having it scroll back to top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291115/java-swing-using-jscrollpane-and-having-it-scroll-back-to-top)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying as well, and found a solution.

There is a useful method called: `setCaretPosition(int)`

After you use

```
component.setText("Text here");
```

You must use

```
component.setCaretPosition(0); //0 will set it to the top
```

In your case, you must add `setCaretPosition()` after `setText`

```
JTextArea txtrTryingTryingTrying = new JTextArea();
scrollPane.setViewportView(txtrTryingTryingTrying);
txtrTryingTryingTrying.setText("-------");
txtrTryingTryingTrying.setCaretPosition(0);
```