# How to scroll JPanel while in design view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, design-view

I am using the Eclipse IDE and I am making a program using the Java Swing Class. This allows me to see the actual design of the GUI while I am making it from the Design View. However, I have a JScrollPane which is for some reason stuck in the middle in the design view. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Scroll bar]

I can scroll the bar when I run the program. But while I am making the GUI, I want to scroll up and down in that scrollPane but I can't.

Does anyone know how I can scroll the panel even while in the Design View of Eclipse?

**EDIT:**
When I run the program, the scroll bar starts at the middle. I want it to start at the top. This is also another problem.

Comment: For your edit, look at [Java Swing - Using JScrollPane and Having it scroll back to top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291115/java-swing-using-jscrollpane-and-having-it-scroll-back-to-top).