# How to prevent JTextPane to autoscroll to bottom

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane in my program. In I like to show the HTML code. Since the JTextPane supports the HTML tag.

But the JTextPane **Auto Scrolls** to the bottom.
I Don't want it to auto scroll

I there any suggestion how to prevent it from autoscrolling.

Comment: Are you continually adding text, or do you do it one time?

Comment: [Java Swing - Using JScrollPane and Having it scroll back to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291115/java-swing-using-jscrollpane-and-having-it-scroll-back-to-top)

Comment: No! I'm not continuously adding text. I add it just one time. Well. For more information I use netbeans IDE. I just drag and drop the text pane after i get html code stored in my database and uses setText() method to add the code to textPane. It works fine. Just scrolls to bottom. That What I don't want.

Comment: Well... Thanks..Your above links worked fine. I got my problem solved.